# How does edit_password_reset_url(some_id_here) resolve to https://example.com/password_resets/some_id_here/edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been looking at [Learn RoR tutorials](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) and we have this route:

```
edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
```

I do not understand how this line:

```
<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

Will translate into:

```
https://example.com/password_resets/<some token here>/edit?email=<user email here>
```

More specifically, how does rails know that the first param (`@user.reset_token`) is suppose to go into the `:id` portion of the url?

The controller `PasswordResetsController`'s `edit` function is defined but blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument passed to `edit_password_reset_url` replaces the `:id` parameter you see when running `rails routes` (`/password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)`). The docs on this can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers).

You can actually update this to use a more relevant parameter, such as `:token` in your case, by using:

```
resources :password_resets, param: :token
```

The url helper also takes a hash of arguments where you can provide additional params, as you're doing with `email`.

*Slightly unnecessary additional explanation*

Were you using a nested route, say, `edit_user_password_reset_url`, this would product something akin to `users/:id/password_resets/:token/edit(.:format)`. The same still applies - the first arg of the helper fills in the variable parameters, though would now take an array, i.e. `edit_user_password_reset_url([@user.id, @token])`

*/end slightly unnecessary additional explanation*

The edit action in your controller can be blank, though typically assigns a resource to be used in the edit view (`/password_resets/edit.html.erb` or similar). This generally contains a form that, when submitted, will hit the `update` action of the same controller.

So, in this case, you may want the edit action to contain the following:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find_by_reset_token(params[:id]) # or params[:token] if you update as above
end
```

Then, in your edit view, you can include a form allowing the user to reset their password.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful! The `Slightly unnecessary additional explanation` is very useful to know as well! Sometimes Rails just feel so magical. So it seems like it doesn't matter what's the param name as long as the first arg fills the expected args in sequence (correct me if my understanding is still wrong).

Comment: You're welcome. I know what you mean, it can certainly seem that way - have a read of the [Rails routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), they should help clear up a lot. Particularly the 'magic' used by the `resources` helper. You're almost right re using the arguments in sequence - that's if they're passed as an array. The second argument is a hash of additional parameters, if required. Hope that helps you crack on!

Comment: Thanks again, this definitely made me feel a bit more confident with Rails, will read the docs again for sure.